# PHP how to retrieve data from cache file

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I work with [Simple PHP Cache](https://github.com/cosenary/Simple-PHP-Cache) Class and set MySql result into file cache when add new article in admin panel Like This:

Cache File:(article.txt)

```
{"204":{"time":1410385682,"expire":0,"data":{"action":["0","description test","title test","1","2",1410530579,"6",205]},
{"205":{"time":1410385682,"expire":0,"data":{"action":["0","description test","title test","1","2",1410530579,"6",205]},
{"207":{"time":1410385682,"expire":0,"data":{"action":["0","description test","title test","1","2",1410530579,"6",205]}
}}
```

For retrieve i can retrieve data from file with this method:

```
    // cache file with the name 'article'
    $c->setCache('article');

    // get cached data by its key (id)
    $result = $c->retrieve('204');

    // display the cached array
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '<pre>';

     OR

    // grab array entry
    $description = $result['description'];
```

This worked, But i dont understand How to retrieve date from cache file in `PHP` loops or php `if/else` Or Fetch list of query.

Example:

In page i need to print list of all article and sort By Date. In MySQL in Retrieve Data Like This:

```
$result = SQL::FETCH("SELECT * FROM DATABASE WHERE id = $id and active = 1 LIMIT 20 ORDER BY timestamp DESC");

foreach ($result as $row){

  echo $row['id];

}
```

Now, how to work with cache file and retrieve data for my example result?!(list all article and sort by date)??

PHP CACHE [HERE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cosenary/Simple-PHP-Cache/master/cache.class.php)

Comment: Looks like that instead of just a cache, you are trying to implement a file-based database which you can query the same way as your database. This is most likely an incorrect approach. Any particular reason why you want to do it this way?

Comment: i work in sharing hosting and not access to APC or Memcached! so i need to reduce my result using file base cache. But i think with file cache most cache block and retrieve block in page!!